# AWS pem doesn't work, but I still have connection alive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key, pem

The previous pem key I used to connect to my ec2 server doesn't work no more after I did ssh keygen or whatever that messed my ssh up. I still have connection to my ec2 instance through my windows cmd, but if i lose this connection I won't be able to connect again since I can't use the AWS console. When I type the command "ssh KEY_NAME" in my cmd it prints "ubuntu@IP: Permission denied (publickey)." and this command previously worked. Can anybody help me out? I came up with possible solutions which I have not tried and am not sure if they'll work.

1. Add the pem key I have to authorized_keys on my ec2 server.
2. Receive a new pem key and get access to my ec2 server.

I honestly have no idea what I should even try.

Comment: See [Troubleshoot connecting to your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html). Note that the command isn't `ssh keyname`. It's `ssh -i <path-to-key> <user>@<host>`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the ownership of the ssh files. I changed the ownership from root to ubuntu and it worked.